# Trouble with a equation in Java

Tags: java, indexing, row, equation

I'm currently working on a 15 puzzle game for Android for school. Sadly I've ran into a problem.

I need to rewrite this equation to get a row and column from it instead of a index. Have a look at the code and se if you guys can help me out!

This takes a row and column and return me a corresponding  index.

```
int index = 4 * (row - 1) + (column - 1);
```

However, now I would like to turn a index into a row and column. 
So does anyone know how to sort of reverse this equation to return a row and a column into two different ints.

Thank,
Mikael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
row = index / 4 + 1;
column = (index % 4) + 1;
```

Note that this (and the original formula) only works if `column < 5` (which it is, of course, for a 15 puzzle).

Comment: make sure you only get the integer part of index/4 and index%4, the floor that is.

Comment: @EuclidesMulémbwè - In Java, `index/4` is integer division and automatically takes the floor. Also, since `index` is an `int`, `index%4` is already an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Try drawing it out for an array and see if you can figure out the pattern. Observe what the index does when you move down a cell, or move right by one.

Note that the indices on the image below are 1-based, but for a java array you'd need 0-based indices.

[image: indices of a 2d array]

Comment: A 15 puzzle uses a 4 x 4 playing field.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page [System of linear equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations). In your case, you have two unknown variables (row and column) and only one equation, so you may have more than one solution (couple of values) for row and column. Note that in your case, you also have constraint concerning the values of row and column since these are array indexes.

Comment: For a 15-puzzle, there are 4 rows and 4 columns. So he has an additional constraint

Comment: In the domain of interest (the lattice points [1,4] x [1,4]), there is only one solution. The material in the article you reference is not appropriate for solving this kind of problem.